# Output of Ansibble task

Tags: ansible, output

I am using command `hcloud` to create cloud server in Hetzner. I get an output like this:

```
changed: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'TEST-VARIABLES', 'server_type': 'cx11', 'os_image': 'ubuntu-20.04', 'server_labels': 'Name=test-server', 'server_location': 'hel1'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": true,
    "hcloud_server": {
        "backup_window": "None",
        "datacenter": "hel1-dc2",
        "delete_protection": false,
        "id": "19461514",
        "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
        "ipv4_address": "11.111.111.111",
        "ipv6": "1a71:7f9:c011:0b09::/64",
        "labels": {
            "Name": "test-server"
        },
        "location": "hel1",
        "name": "TEST-VARIABLES",
        "placement_group": null,
        "rebuild_protection": false,
        "rescue_enabled": false,
        "server_type": "cx11",
        "status": "running"
    },
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "allow_deprecated_image": false,
            "api_token": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
            "backups": null,
            "datacenter": null,
            "delete_protection": null,
            "endpoint": "https://api.SERVER.cloud/v1",
            "firewalls": null,
            "force": false,
            "force_upgrade": false,
            "id": null,
            "image": "ubuntu-20.04",
            "labels": {
                "Name": "test-server"
            },
            "location": "hel1",
            "name": "TEST-VARIABLES",
            "placement_group": null,
            "rebuild_protection": null,
            "rescue_mode": null,
            "server_type": "cx11",
            "ssh_keys": null,
            "state": "present",
            "upgrade_disk": false,
            "user_data": null,
            "volumes": null
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "name": "TEST-VARIABLES",
        "os_image": "ubuntu-20.04",
        "server_labels": "Name=test-server",
        "server_location": "hel1",
        "server_type": "cx11"
    },
    "root_password": "DFLDJFLDFDLFKJDLFKJ"
}
```

I try to get line with `"ipv4_address": "11.111.111.111",` and `"root_password": "DFLDJFLDFDLFKJDLFKJ"`, but when I use task:

```
---

- name: Create a basic server
  hcloud_server:
    api_token: "{{ token }}"
    name: "{{ item.name }}"
    server_type: "{{ item.server_type }}"
    image: "{{ item.os_image }}"
    labels: "{{ item.server_labels }}"
    location: "{{ item.server_location }}"
    state: present
  register: server_info
  with_items: "{{ server }}"

- name: Here IP
  debug:
    var: server_info.root_password
```

I got error:

```
TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/CREATE-server : Here IP.] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "server_info.root_password": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

**Could you please help, how I can get IP line and password line, to use them in the next task (for example to send via email). Thank you!**

Comment: could you show the debug of var  server_info instead server_info.root_password

Comment: Yes, sure. [TASK /etc/ansible/roles/CREATE-server : Here Server info](https://pastebin.com/L3WK55Gg)

Comment: You are using `register` in a loop, please [read the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) on this topic (and look at the debug output you posted).

Comment: => `{{ server_info.results | map(attribute='root_password') }}`

Comment: @Zeitounator Thank you. I see. Could you please tell me, how I can get IP and password in one line?

Comment: Based on the different help you already got in the comments and the below answer, what have you tried and what does not work as expected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you register the content of loop, so your result is a list (`results`):

```
    - name: display
      debug:
        msg: "ip: {{ item.hcloud_server.ipv4_address }} has password: {{ item.root_password }}" 
      loop: "{{ server_info.results }}"
```

result: here you have just one server declared, so just one item in the list results

```
"msg": "ip: 11.111.111.111 has password: DFDFDFDFDFDFDFDF"
```

if you want to limit the output of record, you could add loop_control parameter to loop with argument label:

```
loop: "{{ server_info.results }}"
loop_control:
  label: "{{ item.hcloud_server.ipv4_address }}"
```

you could put another comment if you want with label or even empty string:

```
loop: "{{ server_info.results }}"
loop_control:
  label: "result"
```

Comment: Perfect. It works, but i got to many information.
`TASK [/etc/ansible/roles/CREATE-server : display] 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': True, 'hcloud_server': {'id': '19567955', 'name': 'TEST-VARIABLES', 'ipv4_address': '65.108.213.168', 'ipv6': '2a99:4f9:c099:6b01::/64 .....
    "msg": "ip: 11.111.111.111 has password: DGDGDGDGDGDG"
}`

Could you please tell me, It is possible to separate `"ip: 11.111.111.111 has password: DGDGDGDGDGDG"`

Comment: see my answer, you could add loop_control to limit the output of record selected by using a part of record...  or if you want a report, you could use template module